# Set up DKIM , SPF, DMARC and email sends to spam in Hotmail, gmail

Tags: centos, digital-ocean

I happened to setup Zimbra as our new Client , set up dmarc, dkim, spf, but even at that the webmail by default sends emails directly to spam in Hotmail  / Gmail, without even thinking twice.

What could be the cause? VPS server is hosted on Digital Ocean, and Cent OS 8 is the Linux server used.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of scenarios may cause the mails to be forwarded to the Spam box:

- Server's hostname is incorrect
- Missing PTR Record (reverse DNS) or PTR doesn't match the server's hostname
- Missing or incorrect MX Record, etc

I suggest that you send a test email with random content from your VPS to the email address you'll find on [mail-tester.com](https://mail-tester.com) then click the button to verify your score.

Any score below 8.5 would require that you take action; Required actions will be listed in the report generated by mailtester.

Comment: done as you have said , as for PTR it resolves correctly but still sends to spam email

Comment: Then you should report to hotmail/gmail or any other email host, your domain/IP could require a mitigation to solve the problem.
Consider sending a test email to mail-tester.com's email then share the link here so we can help further